# Pass a variable from inside an IF to the ELSE

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, random

I have a `ASP.Net` application that is a simple number generator. People guess, and it tells them whether or not they are correct. The issue I am having is in order to keep the `randNum` from changing each time the button is clicked to submit the answer (the page is reloaded), it is placed inside a `Page.IsPostBack` statement. The problem is the `randomNum` generated within this `If` is not accessible outside the `If`.

How can I get this variable accessable to other areas of my code while retaining the original `randomNum`? I want to use `IsPostBack`.

```
protected void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false) //the code only runs once when the form is loaded.
    {
        Random myGenerator = new Random();
        myGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNum = myGenerator.Next(1, 50);
     }
        else //code can always run
        {
            int guessedNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);

            if (guessedNum < randomNum)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No. Low.");
                txtGuess.Text = "";
            }
            else if (guessedNum > randomNum)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No. High.");
                txtGuess.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yes");
                txtGuess.Text = "";
            }
        }
}
```

Also, I have tried storing the variable as seen below:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["RANDOM"] = randomNum;
```

and passing it to the else as:

```
int randomNum = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["RANDOM"]);
```

But doing this always results in a value of 0.

This is the only page that needs to use the variable. It does not need passed across pages, just functions.

Comment: never store such things in session and try to avoid session as much as possible. move the randomNum variable outside of the if condition. simple as that or if you need access to it in other areas of code, move it to make it a global variable (i.e after your class decleration

Comment: @Ahmedilyas He's asking how to make it accessible across requests.

Comment: Global variables will not stay populated on postback.  You need to use session or viewstate.

Comment: If it is moved outside the if statement, the random function will be rerun each time the page is re-loaded (the user clicks a button) and the random number will constantly change. This is not desired function.

Comment: @YamMarcovic - thanks, it wasn't clear

Comment: Well, you should indeed use the viewstate or the session variable, anything that lets you hold a value in this stateless environement that the web is... I don't know why Ahmed advises not to use session and avoid them, session are not bad...

Comment: you could use caching obviously. or a cookie. but still, the question was not clear enough to say if it is to be persisted across all pages or not. thus the only advice was given was tailored to that

Comment: Why won't you use sessions but use a cookie instead ?

Comment: The problem is the IsPostback check does not belong in a button click event. It's always a postback in a button click event.

Comment: See my answer, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page.IsPostBack does not belong in a button click event.  It needs to be added to Page_Load.
The way you have it now, it will always hit the else. i.e. it's always a postback in a button click.

```
protected void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int randomNum = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["RANDOM"]);
        int guessedNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);

        if (guessedNum < randomNum)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No. Low.");
            txtGuess.Text = "";
        }
        else if (guessedNum > randomNum)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No. High.");
            txtGuess.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
            txtGuess.Text = "";
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false) //the code only runs once when the form is loaded.
    {
        Random myGenerator = new Random();
        myGenerator = new Random();
       int randomNum = myGenerator.Next(1, 50);
       HttpContext.Current.Session["RANDOM"] = randomNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. I had just learned about using sessions to pass the variables around so that helped too!